# Saving Before Common Era (BCE) Date

Tags: sqlite, date

I'm creating book writing software.

The problem is, when user create story that happen say in year `200 BCE` [ [CE / BCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Era) wiki], how to store this date in `SQLite` so I can sort it like normal `DateTime`.

Comment: How are you storing your other dates?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the [built-in date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) says:

> These functions only work for dates between 0000-01-01 00:00:00 and 9999-12-31 23:59:59.

However, SQLite does not have a separate data type for dates; it just uses numbers or strings, and interprets them as dates only when you apply a date function to them.

If you do not actually need to use the SQLite date functions, you can use any type and format, as long as it sorts correctly.
Strings like `yyyy-mm-dd` do not sort correctly for BCE dates, so you have to use numbers (Julian days, or Unix timestamps, or any other format).